# JSON display key and values in different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON object that has different keys in one long single object (> 10,000 lines). How can I iterate through each key and display the key in one div and its value in another div using js?

I have a variable holding this object and console logging them I can see them as they should be. But my problem lies in grabbing each one since the keys are always different. Normally el.key will get the key/value you are after but since the key is always changing from pair to pair how can I access all keys and send them to the div#keys and then grab all the values and send them to div#values?

Here's a snippet of the JSON object:

```
{
   10: 1
   11: 1
   13: 1
   15: 1
   20: 1
   21: 2
   22: 2
   25: 2
   28: 3
   32: 1
   33: 3
   37: 1
   38: 1
   39: 2
   41: 1
   45: 2
}
```

Sample html:

```
<div id="keys">keys go here</div>
<div id="values">values go here</div>
```

Thanks,

Sergio

Comment: `k = Object.keys(obj);` and `v = k.map(x => obj[x]);`. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ofurryd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var test = {10: 1,11: 1,13: 1,15: 1,20: 1,21: 2,22: 2,25: 2,28: 3,32: 
1,33: 3,37: 1,38: 1,39: 2,41: 1,45: 2};

for(var i in test){
    document.getElementById('keys').innerHTML += i + ' ,';
    document.getElementById('values').innerHTML += test[i] + ' ,';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get all keys via `Object.keys(yourObject)`. You can also get the key value via `Object.entries(yourObject)`. Once you have an array with all key and all value, you can simply `join` the array and add it to your div :

`document.getElementById("keys").innerHTML = keys;`

jsbin here : https://jsbin.com/vabeboyexo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents;

```
var input = {
  10: 1,
  11: 1,
  13: 1,
  15: 1,
  20: 1,
  21: 2,
  22: 2,
  25: 2,
  28: 3,
  32: 1,
  33: 3,
  37: 1,
  38: 1,
  39: 2,
  41: 1,
  45: 2
};

function createKV(kv, isKey) {

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.width = "100px";
  div.style.height = "100px";

  var color = isKey ? "green" : "blue";

  div.style.background = color;
  div.style.color = "white";
  div.innerHTML = kv;

  var placing = isKey ? "keys" : "values";

  document.getElementById(placing).appendChild(div);

}

for (var key in input) {
  console.log(key);
  createKV(key, true);
  console.log(input[key]);
  createKV(input[key], false);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1k6ndwxb/1/

But, it can be done very differently too :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without loop like: (Works only in Chrome & FireFox as [`Object.values(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) is not supported yet in other browsers)

```js
var obj = {
  10: 1,
  11: 4,
  15: 2
};

document.getElementById("keys").innerHTML = Object.keys(obj);
document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = Object.values(obj);
```

```html
<div id="keys">keys go here</div>
<div id="values">values go here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(YourJsonVar).each(function(){
$('#keys').append(this.key);
$('#values').append(this.value)

})
```

the each function (JQ) is used for iterating anything ..from variable values to elements in the dom so you are just running a for loop over your json value

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.